# C# smartcard working on terminal

Tags: c#, x509, x509certificate2

I wrote this code and it's working perfect when we have running app on this same PC where we plug smartcards.

But how I need to do to make this code running when my app is run on terminal and user has smartcards connect to his own PC.

On terminal session I allow to use smartcard for terminal.

User can see this cert but when this cert was chosen then I get error about no private key..

How to use smartcard on a remote PC ?

```
private X509Certificate2 LetUserChooseCertificate()
{
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;

        try
        {
            // Open the store of personal certificates.
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);//StoreName.My  StoreLocation.CurrentUser
            //X509Store store = new X509Store("addressbook", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

            X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
            X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Signing", "Choose cert", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

            if (scollection != null && scollection.Count == 1)
            {
                cert = scollection[0];                 
                if (cert.HasPrivateKey == false)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("This certificate does not have a private key associated with it");
                    //cert = null; 
                }
            }

            store.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Unable to get the private key");
            //cert = null;
        }

        return cert;
}
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with smartcards. The OS abstract away the storage location and operation of smartcards and certificates. The same code will work correctly on the terminal *if* smart card redirection is configured correctly. This is an infrastructure, not a programming issue. Check for example [Smart Card and Remote Desktop Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404286(v=ws.10).aspx). Also check your RDP settings. Smart Card redirection is enabled by default

Comment: Problem was solved. Smartcards drivers should be installed on remote machine but in my case user was incorrectly install this drivers.